# why this function always crashes?

Tags: c, recursion

Can anyone tell me why `fillpool` always crashes? Maybe there is an infinite recursion, but where?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 5

bool IsNotValidIndex(int Row , int Column)
{
  if((Row >= N || Row < 0) || (Column >= N || Column < 0))
      return true ;
  return false ;
}

void fillpool(int row , int column , int picture[N][N])
{
  if(IsNotValidIndex(row , column))
    return ;
  if(picture[row][column] == 0)
    return ;
  picture[row][column] = 2 ;
  fillpool(row + 1 , column , picture) ;
  fillpool(row - 1 , column , picture) ;
  fillpool(row ,column + 1 , picture) ;
  fillpool(row , column -1 , picture) ;
}
```

Comment: `fillpool(row + 1 , column , picture) ;` and `fillpool(row - 1 , column , picture) ;` are playing ping-pong (please use a debugger or place some log output)

Comment: It is rarely appropriate to use both c++ and c tags. They are different languages.

Comment: @DieterLücking but i have   if(IsNotValidIndex(row , column)) which take care of this

Comment: @AmeenAli No, it doesn't take care of this. It takes care of what would be another problem, but not the infinite recursion. And if you use a debugger of put some logging like Dieter Lücking suggested, and check which values `row` and `column` take, it will be clear why `IsNotValidIndex` does not and cannot prevent the infinite recursion.

Comment: @Dieter is right. You need to fix your logic.

Comment: Your first port of call when debugging code should be to use your debugger.

Comment: If `row == 0`, then your index is valid, but `fillpool(row - 1, ...)` is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @rwols Wrong. The OP has opted for a design where `fillpool(-1, ...)` is valid and does nothing.

Comment: debugger is your friend

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "please debug my code for me" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite recursion because you're setting the value of a row/col to "2" but then you check for it to be "0".  So you're constantly setting the values to 2 over and over again.  The infinite recursion happens because you're calling fillpool for "row+1" which will then do fillpool for "row-1" and so you get infinite recursion (and the same thing would happen with column+1 but you never reach there).

Answer (score 0):

A code walk-through quickly makes the problem clear, the process is easily done by stepping the code in your debugger.

Let's say you call it with `row = col = 2`, this sets `2,2`:

```
00000
00000
00200
00000
00000
```

Then you call `fillpool(row + 1 , column , picture)`, which recurses until row is invalid:

```
00000
00000
00200
00200
00200
```

Then `fillpool(row - 1 , column , picture)` is called which sets `1,2`:

```
00000
00200
00200
00200
00200
```

Then calls `fillpool(row + 1 , column , picture)`, but that refers to `2,2` so you are exactly at your start condition, so will repeat the above sequence until the stack is exhausted.

The 4-way flood fill algorithm is thus (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill):

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

You have incorrectly coded step 1 by testing for 0 but filling with 2:

if(picture[row][column] == 2)
    return ;